# Problem getting image's width to work using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, width

I'm trying to load and resize an image using jQuery.

I have this code:

```
var myImg = $("#myImage");
myImg.attr("src", "/Content/TestImage.jpg");
myImg.attr("width", "750px");
```

The image is being loaded, but the width attribute is not taking effect.  I've tried with both a width being defined in the CSS (i.e., width: 200px;) and without a width being defined.

I've also tried setting the width before setting the src attribute, but that didn't make any difference either.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what the issue might be?

Comment: is the image inside any other container like div?  you can try also myImg.width(750)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
myImg.width(750);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JtN26/

Answer (score 0):

Set the width using CSS like this

```
myImg.css({width:750})
```